# How can I view a diff for a single file from a diff file with multiple files?

Tags: vimdiff, git

I have a diff file generated by
`git diff HEAD~2 > alldiff`.
Is it possible to view the diff for any one file using `alldiff`?
For example, `somecmd alldiff file1withchanges` will use `alldiff` to show changes in `file1withchanges` in `vimdiff`.

Answer (score 0):

TIL about this: [Is it possible to use vimdiff's side by side view with a regular diff file?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/36567/is-it-possible-to-use-vimdiffs-side-by-side-view-with-a-regular-diff-file)

`:help diffpatch` is your answer.

You just need to say

```
:diffpatch alldiff
```

---

Other answer before I knew that^

I'm not normally one to recommend plugins, but I recommend using [vim-fugitive](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive). There is a command, `:GDiffsplit`, that does exactly what you want.

In the buffer you're interested in, simply say `:GDiffsplit HEAD~2` and fugitive will do the rest:

- Get git to create the diff
- open a temp buffer with a copy of the file
- Apply the diff
- run `:diffthis` on the two buffers

Here is me trying to write that as a vimscript function

```
function! do_the_fugitive_thing(revision)
  " Get git to create the diff
  let my_file = expand("%")
  let my_patch = "/tmp/ari.patch"
  system("git diff ".a:revision." -- ".my_file." > ")

  " open a temp buffer with a copy of the file
  vsp temp_buffer
  set filetype=nofile
  execute "read ".my_file

  " Apply the diff
  system("patch < ".my_patch)
  edit! % " reload buffer after patch application

  " run `:diffthis` on the two buffers
  bufdo diffthis
endfunction
```

Let me know if this works! Or if you don't know vimscript enough then don't worry about it and just use the plugin...

Comment: The problem with `:diffpatch` is that it doesn't work if there are multiple diffs in the same file, which is likely to be the case for the result of `git diff`.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble good point. Although I likely suspect OP doesn’t even want to use `git diff` without a specific filepath for diff creation in the first place…

Comment: Given that that is precisely the premise of the question, I would _not_ assume that…

Comment: @D.BenKnoble when you’re right, you’re right … literally in the title… hard to pull myself out of the context of achieving the solution (the vimdiff window) and back to the ask! When the question said patch I didn’t think it implied a git diff. It no longer says patch tho.